# middle text in a div

Tags: html, css

Why is the text in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/7EYZe/ not in the vertical center?

How can I middle the text?

***EDIT:***
Now I have two or more lines of text:
http://jsfiddle.net/7EYZe/12/

How can I display this properly?

Comment: Can there be more than one line of text? Do you need IE7 support?

Comment: [Read this](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following css will center text in a div by using padding instead of height:

```
 .centerText
    {
        padding: 90px 0;
        font-size: 18px;
        border:solid 1px #000;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

That's an incorrect use of `vertical-align`.  It doesn't know what object to vertically align itself to.

Here is one dynamic, table-less solution: http://jsfiddle.net/imoda/7EYZe/14/

```
<style type="text/css">
    div {
        height:200px;    
        width:200px;
        border:solid 1px black;
    }

    .aligner {
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .align {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <span class="aligner"></span>
    <span class="align">blabla</span>
</div>
```

Comment: should I add DOM element: <span class="aligner"></span> for this?? Isn't it wrong use??

Comment: It will fails to work if the text is more than 200px long (new line) http://jsfiddle.net/7EYZe/221/

Answer (score 2):

Add text-align: center; and display: table-cell; to center it in middle of the box.

```
div {
    height:200px;    
    width:200px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: I do not believe `display: table-cell;` is supported by IE... half of visitors.

Comment: @Sparky672 it is supported by IE8 and newer. You have a point though.

Comment: I'll take your word for it... I was having trouble finding definitive information on IE version support.

Answer (score 0):

Use `line-height:200px`, e.g.

```
div {
  border:solid 1px black;
  height:200px; 
  line-height:200px;  
  width:200px;
}
```

Also, in your example, you won't need `vertical-align:middle`.  That style means that the `div` will be vertically aligned *to its parent element*.  It doesn't mean the text inside will be vertically aligned.

Comment: It should be noted that this `line-height` solution will only work on one line of text.

Comment: This is not a dynamic solution.

Answer (score 0):

The div is vertically aligned within whatever surrounds it. That doesn't affect what's inside. Make it smaller, in fact remove the width, and put it inside something bigger.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, vertical-align was mainly designed for specifying the behaviour of table-cells. Although the name suggests that any content shall be aligned in the middle, it simply does not.

You can find a very good article [here](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) about what vertical-align really is and how to achieve your intended purpose - aligning the text vertically inside your div.

Answer (score -1):

This is way too much of a pain to do with a div. Use a table cell instead:
html: `<table><tr><td>My Text</td></tr></table>`
css: `td { vertical-align: middle; }`

Comment: Although I'm not a downvoter, @muirbot might be interested to know why the -1 votes.  For more than a decade, table based layouts are generally frowned upon for non-tabular data, since current CSS techniques allow better DOM manipulation.  It falls in the "bad practice" category, thus the downvotes.

Comment: I would agree with @Steve in a situation where "current CSS techniques allow for better DOM manipulation", but there simply is no current CSS technique for middle vertical alignment of text of arbitrary length. The chosen answer will need adjustment every time the content changes.